# How to add one more string in the ArrayList using Groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am using SoapUI to test REST service. I wanted to add if v_manageCustomText value is present then i need to add that in dispositionNames else dispositionNames as is.

```
 def dispositionNames = ["ApproveFraud","ApproveNonFraud","System Error"]
   log.info(dispositionNames.getClass().getSimpleName())
   log.info(context.testCase.getPropertyValue("v_manageCustomText"))
   if(context.testCase.getPropertyValue("v_manageCustomDisposition") !="")
    {
    value = context.testCase.getPropertyValue("v_manageCustomDisposition") 
    dispositionNames = dispositionNames.add(value)
    log.info dispositionNames
    log.info(dispositionNames.getClass().getSimpleName())
    }
```

I am getting following results. It looks that i after i adding the value it becomes boolean type.

```
Mon Oct 30 15:48:43 IST 2017:INFO:CustomDisposition1509102136431
Mon Oct 30 15:48:43 IST 2017:INFO:true
Mon Oct 30 15:48:43 IST 2017:INFO:Boolean
```

Comment: This line is wrong: dispositionNames = dispositionNames.add(value)
Add returns a boolean, just remove the assignment.

Comment: Thanks for pointing.. If I use dispositionNames.add(value) only then it is working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy is a "weakly typed language", which means that on the one hand you don't need to define the type of a variable. On the other hand the variable can change mid-run if you assign it a value of a different type.

http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html

As @adamcooney mentioned, you used the line:

```
dispositionNames = dispositionNames.add(value)
```

Which performs the operation of adding a `value` to `dispositionNames`. And then returns `true` to indicate that the `add` operation was succesful.

This `true` is then assigned back into `dispositionNames` var, which changes it's value from `List` to `Boolean`. This is why you see this behaviour.